# how to replace the title name of a data frame with data in row?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

[image]

I want to replace the title names with row index [0] or match the title name with row[0], can anyone please help

Comment: You have a problem when you read the csv? You can define the header line at import: `pandas.read_csv('your/path.csv', header=1)`

Comment: If not, than 'pop' the first line and replace the column names: `df, header = df.drop(df.head(1).index), df.head(1)` `df.columns = header.values.to_list()`

Comment: What do you want the column name to be when there is a actual column name in both the column and the first row? For example, how do you want to choose between `Development (Non Construction Costs)` and `Reporting`

Comment: Thank you @syker pandas.read_csv('your/path.csv', header=1) this helps me

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.